# Regex to skip first word and parse the rest of the message

Tags: regex, logstash-grok

I've been trying to get the right regex for skipping the first word and parsing the rest of the message.

```
I've been testing the regex by running Logstash locally

grok {
    match => { "resource" => "/[^/]+/[^/]+(/|)(?<repo>[^/]+)?(/%{GREEDYDATA:resource_path})?" }
      }

Test Messages:

/list/Lighter-test-group/xyz/123
/list/
/list

For messages,

/list/Lighter-test-group/xyz/123 gives us repo value as "Lighter-test-group" which is valid
/list/ gives us repo value as null which is valid
but /list gives repo value as "list" which is an invalid value. The correct value needs to be empty or null.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are restricted to using one really long regex but I would look into [custom patterns](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/master/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns) to ignore the first word.

Using this [grok debugger](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match), I setup some custom patterns in the 3rd box:

```
IGNORE /\b\w+\b
REPO [A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9+\-.]+)+
```

And tested out this grok pattern in the 2nd box:

```
%{IGNORE}(/)?(%{REPO:repo})?(%{GREEDYDATA:resource_path})
```

Using these custom patterns, I was able to get what I think is your desired output but test them out with more use cases if you have any.